# Every integer, and every positive integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Construct $A_k = (a_1, …, a_k)$ and $D_k = (d_1, …, d_k)$ inductively from $a_1 = d_1 = 0$, starting with $k = 1$, as follows:  let $h$ be the least integer $>-a_k$ such that $h \not\in D_k$ and $a_k + h \not\in A_k$, and let $a_{k+1} = a_k + h$ and $d_{k+1} = h$.  Is every integer in $D_\infty$ and every positive integer in $A_\infty$?  If so, does this happen if $a_1$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integer and $d_1$ an arbitrary integer?

Example using $a_1 = d_1 = 0$:  $D_8 = (0,1,2,-1,3,4,-5,6)$ and $A_8 = (0,1,3,2,5,9,4,10)$.

Comment: How does this construction arise?

Comment: It looks very similar to some of the problems on this website: http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/integer/unsolved.html

Comment: I think, every positive integer appears in $A_n$. Indeed, if $m$ is the minimal positive integer such that $m\notin A_n$, numbers $1,\dots,m-1$ appear as $a_k$ for, say, $k<N$. Choose $n$ so that $a_n>\max(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$, $a_n>m+\max(|d_1|,\dots,|d_N|)$. Why $a_{n+1}\ne m$? The reason may be that $d_k=m-a_n$ for some $k\leq n$, then $a_{k}=a_{k-1}+d_k=m+(a_{k-1}-a_n)<m$, thus $k<N$ and $a_n=m-d_k$ is too small.